# Trouble with Python excersice - Convert letters to numbers in order (using ord and chr)

Tags: python, numbers, type-conversion, letters

I am sorry, but I am at a loss here everyone. No real idea where to start. I am new to Python and its been many years since I last tried programming of any kind. I was never very experienced. I am following this Python course online and have come to a dead end on an exercise. It is going off of the previous example.

```
x = int(input())
if x>=1 and x<=26:
    print('letter', x, 'in the alphabet:', chr(ord('A')+(x-1)))
else:
    print('invalid input:', x)
```

This example program converts numbers to letters. So, 'A' = 1 and 'B' = 2. 
It now wants me to make a program just like this but the opposite. I am supposed to start with this line:

```
letter = input()
```

Here is what the exercise describes:

Coding Exercise: 26 Letters
Write a program which does the reverse of the example above: it should take a character as input and output the corresponding number (between 1 and 26). Your program should only accept capital letters. As error-checking, print invalid if the input is not a capital letter

Now this is I can do, but not the way it wants me to do it, nor the way I should. I could do something like this:

```
if letter == 'A':
    letter = int(1)
    print(letter)
elif letter == 'B':
    letter = int(2)
    print(letter)
```

Of course that would be very long and sloppy. Does anyone have any advice for me? This one has me stuck. I'm sorry, I know this is probably very simple, this just seems much more complicated to me than it should be. I have tried looking this up but everything I find online is different enough that I cannot figure out how to implement it into this code. To be honest the chr and ord stuff confuses me greatly. I appreciate it for anyone who stuck around long enough to read this. Thank you. I have no idea what to do anymore with this one. Also, this is my very first time posting anything here, so if I did anything sloppy or wrong, I apologize and will delete/edit it as soon as I can.

The problem can be found here: https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/9-else-and-or-not/

Adding a little information. CScircles requires that A = 1 instead of 0. Thanks for the quick replies. I will be working on this again later today.

Comment: Use `ord` to get the numeric value of the character, then subtract a number from it so that "A"'s code becomes 0. What about `ord` confuses you?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `ord` function again, that you used in the previous exercise to get the char number of the character. Then you can substract the char value of the character `A` to get a value between `1` and `26`.

```
inp = input()
if (len(inp) > 1 or inp != inp.upper()):
    print("invalid input")
else:
    print(ord(inp)-ord("A")+1)
```

The `ord(x)` function accepts a character `x` (e.g. any `UTF8` character) and returns an integer. This integer value represents the number of the character in the encoding table: Let's take a look at the table for `ascii` below.
[image]
Here you see the `char` values and the `dec`/`int` values of the characters. For example the character `A` is represented by the `int` value `65`, and so on.

The `chr(x)` function is doing the opposite: it takes the `int` value and returns the `char` which is represented by this, this means:

```
ord("A") = 65
chr(65) = "A"
chr(ord(anyCharacter)) = anyCharacter
```